# Simple Q-Table Learning: Understanding Example Code

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm trying to follow a tutorial for Q-Table learning from [this source](https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-0-q-learning-with-tables-and-neural-networks-d195264329d0), and am having difficulty understanding a small piece of the code. Here's the entire block:

```
import gym
import numpy as np


env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v0')

#Initialize table with all zeros
Q = np.zeros([env.observation_space.n,env.action_space.n])
# Set learning parameters
lr = .8
y = .95
num_episodes = 2000
#create lists to contain total rewards and steps per episode
#jList = []
rList = []
for i in range(num_episodes):
    #Reset environment and get first new observation
    s = env.reset()
    rAll = 0
    d = False
    j = 0
    #The Q-Table learning algorithm
    while j < 99:
        j+=1
        #Choose an action by greedily (with noise) picking from Q table
        a = np.argmax(Q[s,:] + np.random.randn(1,env.action_space.n)*(1./(i+1)))
        #Get new state and reward from environment
        s1,r,d,_ = env.step(a)
        #Update Q-Table with new knowledge
        Q[s,a] = Q[s,a] + lr*(r + y*np.max(Q[s1,:]) - Q[s,a])
        rAll += r
        s = s1
        if d == True:
            break
    #jList.append(j)
    rList.append(rAll)


print "Score over time: " +  str(sum(rList)/num_episodes)

print "Final Q-Table Values"
print Q
```

The code runs well and I'm able to print my results, but here is where I'm having difficulties:

```
a = np.argmax(Q[s,:] + np.random.randn(1,env.action_space.n)*(1./(i+1)))
```

My question is, why are we multiplying by 1/(i+1)? Is this supposed to be an implementation of epsilon annealing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, why are we multiplying by 1/(i+1)? Is this supposed to be an implementation of epsilon annealing?

The code looks like a relatively ad-hoc* adjustment to ensure early exploration, and an alternative to $\epsilon$-greedy action choice. The `1/(i+1)` factor is *similar* to decaying $\epsilon$, but not identical.

$\epsilon$-greedy with the same decay factor might look like this:

```
a = np.argmax(Q[s,:])
if epsilon/(1+math.sqrt(i)) > random.random():
    a = random.randrange(0, env.action_space.n)
```

The `math.sqrt(i)` is just a suggestion, but I feel that `epsilon/(1+i)` is probably too aggressive and would cut off exploration too quickly.

It is not something I have seen before when studying Q-Learning (e.g. in David Silver's lectures or Sutton & Barto's book). However, Q-Learning is not predicated on using *any* specific action choice, it just needs enough exploration in the behaviour policy. For the given problem adding some noise to a greedy selection obviously works well enough. Technically for guaranteed convergence tabular Q-Learning needs infinite exploration over infinite time steps. The code as supplied *does indeed do that* because the noise is unbound from the Normal distribution. So there is always some small finite chance of selecting an action with a relatively low action-value estimate and refining that estimate later.

However, the fast decay (1/episode number) and initial scaling factor for the noise are both hyperparameters that need tuning to the problem. You might prefer something more standard from the literature such as $\epsilon$-greedy, Gibbs sampling or upper-confidence-bound action selection (the example is quite similar to UCB, in that it adds to the Q-values before taking the max).

---

* Perhaps the approach used in the example has a name (some variation of "Noisy Action Selection") but I don't know it, and could not find it on a quick search.

Comment: Perhaps interestingly, this noisy action selection does appear to work rather well; to get something comparable with $\epsilon_i$-greedy action selection on the given example, I had to go all the way to $\epsilon_i = 1/(i^{1/20}+1)$ and bump the number of episodes.